# Unable to set mandatory headers for ContactOriginData PATCH in batch mode

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

According to the [integration guide for Contacts OData](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0f9408e4921e4ba3bb4a7a1f75f837a7/2102.500/en-US/95f2c87395bb4dda905010423029c23e.html) the `Sap-Cuan-SequenceId` header is mandatory when updating a ContactOriginData record. When updating in singleton mode I am able to set this header as follows and it works without issue:

```
service
  .updateContactOriginData(contact)
  .withHeader("Sap-Cuan-SequenceId", "PatchUpdate")
  .executeRequest(destination);
```

However, there is no option to set this header when performing the same update in batch mode:

```
service
  .batch()
  .beginChangeSet()
  .updateContactOriginData(contact)
  .withHeader(...) // this option does not exist
  .endChangeSet()
  .executeRequest(destination);
```

When I run the batch one my SAP Import Monitor  shows the error:

```
Invalid content in field Sap-Cuan-SequenceId
```

Is it possible to set this header in batch mode and I'm just not seeing how? I am using version `3.39.0` of the SDK. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This clearly looks like an implementation shortcoming. The SDK has a new API for [OData BATCH in the OData v4 client](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v4-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#batch-requests) which shouldn't have this issue. Mentioned service exposes OData v2 only and the OData v2 BATCH implementation has been historically different. For compatibility reasons, it has to be kept like this. We plan to provide a parallel implementation to align it with OData v4 and fix many minor and major inconsistencies.

If this is super urgent we can try to provide a workaround using the SDK's [generic OData client](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/generic-untyped-odata-client) otherwise create an issue in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Java&template=sap-cloud-sdk-for-java-issue.md&title=) and the SDK team will update you when the fix for adding headers is going to be released.

Comment: Ok, thank you @ArtyomKovalyov  for the reply. I think because we are using SAP S/4HANA Cloud it only supports OData v2. I will create an issue in the GH repo.

Comment: I've logged the issue with them: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues/156

Comment: Hi @kurts, thanks for reporting it. We'll post back here as well when the fix is ready to let the community easily find it.